Unable to find a version of System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow that is compatible with Dse 2.10.4 System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow' (>= 4.6.0 && < 5.0.0)'
I am currently attempting to upgrade the our own Nuget package in our WCF service, but I am encountering a compatibility issue as detailed below:
Error: Unable to find a version of 'System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow' that is compatible with 'Dse 2.10.4 constraint: System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow (>= 4.6.0 && < 5.0.0)'.
I have checked both the our own nuget package and WCF Service configuration files, and they are utilizing the same version for the reported package, as shown below:
<package id="System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow" version="4.6.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Dse" version="2.10.4" targetFramework="net461" />

Anyone able to provide any suggestions to help resolve this issue? That would be great :)

did you forget to include some example?

The error suggests a potential mismatch in the dependency tree. Verify all referenced packages for conflicting System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow versions. Use the following command in the Package Manager Console:
dotnet list package --include-transitive
Look for any transitive dependencies referencing a different version of System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.

Hi @Md hussain, you can set a constraint  to avoid update package System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflo when you  upgrade the your own Nuget package in your WCF service.

By default, updating a package always installs the latest version available from the package source. Based on your description, i guess the package  System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow will be updated automatically to latest version when you upgrade  your own Nuget packages.
You can set a constraint to avoid update package System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow low than 4.6.0 or high than 5.0.0 because Dse 2.10.4 depends on the version >= 4.6.0 && < 5.0.0.
Add the allowedVersions attribute with your desired version range.
   <package id="System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow" version="4.6.0" allowedVersions="[4.6.0,5.0.0)" />

Referred Doc:
Constraints on upgrade versions
